# How to increase the size of a Note field type?

Tags: custom-fields, textarea

Does the 'Note' custom field type have a limitation of 12000 characters? If so how can I increase its limit to three fold or four fold?

Answer (score 2):

you can update the field type from text to longtext

```
ALTER TABLE `civicrm_value_table_name` MODIFY `field_name` LONGTEXT DEFAULT NULL;
```